# Running jQuery on a static HTML file from Bash

Tags: jquery, python, bash

I'm trying to write a simple script to simply check a webpage for a specific value:

```
$("a#infgHeader").text() == "Delivered";
```

I'd like to automate this from a Bash script to be run at an interval. I'm also fine with using Python. I need to essentially make an HTTP request, get the response, and have a way to intelligently query the result. Is there a library which will help me with the querying part?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Xpath is great for querying html.

Something like this:

```
//a[@id='infgHeader']/@text
```

In chrome developer tool you can use the search box in the Elements tab to test the expression.

Quick run in terminal:

```
$echo '<div id="test" text="foo">Hello</div>' | xpath '//div[@id="test"]/@text' 
Found 1 nodes:
-- NODE --
 text="foo"
```

Comment: Hooray for xPath! I was wondering if it would be of help here. I didn't know because HTML != XML, but hey, if it works, it works.

Comment: `xpath` works poorly with not-strictly-XML HTML code. When running it on a 100-line HTML snippet, it freezes for a minute then dies with a "mismatched tag" error, apparently because the code had `<img>` and not `<img />`.

Comment: Yes, xpath is not reliable. Guess I'll use [regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) then.

Answer (score 2):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/spynner/1.10

Spynner will let you select elements from the dom using jquery syntax.

Or there are other libraries that let you parse HTML.  BeautifulSoup, lxml

Answer (score 1):

Alex MacCaw wrote up a nice post that does just what you're asking using node.js / JavaScript. There are a LOT of capabilities it brings too.

http://alexmaccaw.com/posts/node_jquery_xml_parsing

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done something like this using [nodejs](http://nodejs.org) + [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) both are well documented with a low entry barrier.

Answer (score 0):

To parse html is not trivial for general websites, because html may not be prefect and DOM can be modified by java-script on the fly, so parsing html may not make sense in such case.

Best way is to use a browser and directly access the DOM, for that you can use a headless browser like [phontomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/), so you can script it and check whatever you need to check